# Filter a array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, regex, arrays, filter

I have been bogged down in this for the past few days. I have searched and searched but the examples and techniques posted only works partially, and non of them are in loops. Basically what i am trying to do is make a filter for the Apache log file. With the following code i can split the Apache log into its basic chunks. Using these chunks i want to create filters.

```
<?php

$out = array();

exec('tail -n 5 /var/log/httpd/error_log',$out);



    foreach($out as $output){
    preg_match('~^\[(.*?)\]~',$output,$date);
    preg_match('~\ \[([a-z]*?)\] ~',$output,$type);
    preg_match('~\ \[client ([0-9\.]*)\]~',$output,$client);
    preg_match('~[a-z\A-Z\.0-9][^\]]*$~',$output,$message);


echo "</br>";
echo "Date chunk = ";
print_r($date[0]);

echo "</br>";
echo "Type chunk = ";
print_r($type[0]);

echo "</br>";
echo "Client chunk =";
print_r ($client[0]);

echo "</br>";
echo "Message chunk = ";
print_r ($message[0]);

echo "</br>";


}


?>
```

Here is a screen shot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsUyJ.png

In apache log file, the type chunk can be a [error] or a [Notice], i want to have a way to filter the log file and view them. For example i only want the logs containing [error] type to appear, or type with [Notice] to appear, even the date chunk can be used as filters to view logs from different days. I can make a php drop down option to make the user choose [error] or [Notice], but how do i use them to filter out the logs and view them?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot guys, very helpful insight from both of you. After brainstorming for a while, i figured it would be better to implement a method directly from centos, rather than full php. I am posting the method for any one else who might find this helpful

You can use Bash/PHP to fill the $Day variable, it should be in Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed etc format.The returning log lines are only the ones of $Day from the 1000 lines. Beauty of awk is you can adjust this to filter by Date/type/ip =), just change if $1 to $2,$3 etc and change the $Day variable to the correct type.

```
tail -n 1000 /var/log/httpd/error_log | awk -F " " '{if $1 =="[Tue") print $all}'
```

For php you need to escape.

```
"tail -n 1000 /var/log/httpd/error_log | awk -F \" \" '{if $1 == \"[$Day\") print $all}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here regexp for you (use it with preg_match_all):

```
(\[[^\]]+\])\s(\[[^\]]+\])\s(\[[^]]+\]):\s([^$]+)
```

with this string, for example

```
[Thu Jan 23 02:00:48 2014] [error] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file
```

preg_match_all returns

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => [Thu Jan 23 02:00:48 2014] [error] [mod_geoip]: Error while opening data file
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => [Thu Jan 23 02:00:48 2014]
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => [error]
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => [mod_geoip]
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => Error while opening data file
    )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a filter form  with the following values and you will do the necessary input validation properly:

```
Log Type : error, notice(select options)
start date : filter start date()
end date : filter end date
```

And in your php file

```
$search_type = isset($_POST['log_type'])?"[".$_POST['log_type']."]":FALSE;
$start_date = isset($_POST['start_date'])?$_POST['start_date']:FALSE;
$end_date = isset($_POST['end_date'])?$_POST['end_date']:FALSE;
$result= array();
foreach($out as $output){
  $fl = false;
  $tempStr = substr(substr($date[0],0,-1),1);
  ..................
  ....................
  if( $search_type && ($type[0]==$search_type){
       $fl = true;
  }
  if($start_date){
        if( strtotime($start_date." 0:0:0 ") >= strtotime($tempstr) ){
             $fl=true;
        }
  }
  if($end_date){
        if( strtotime($end_date." 0:0:0 ") <= strtotime($tempstr) ){
             $fl=true;
        }
  }
  if($fl==true){
     $result[] = array('date'=>date[0],'type'=>$type[0],'client'=>$client[0],'message'=>$message[0]); 
  }
}
```

print_r($result;)